# Installing let's encrypt key in wildfly backend

Tags: java, https, wildfly, keystore, lets-encrypt

I had generated a valid key with let's encrypt so i have pem files in my server.

But for my wildfly i tried to generate key with keystore but it didn't work correctly.

how can i get a valid ssl certificate keystore for my wildfly to call it from my front-end without having broken https.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the answer for my question :

openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out cert.pkcs12

keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore trustedkey.keystore -srckeystore cert.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12